# Using which field matched in a multimatch query in a function score

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a multimatch query which I am using across 5 fields. I am also using a function score to combine various factors into the score. I would like to add a factor to this so that results that matched on one of the fields is increased (adding a large number so that matches on this field always have the highest score).

I know that I can use highlighting to find out which fields were matched, but how can I access that information in the function score script?

Here's what I have so far (using NEST, but that shouldn't make a difference).

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<TopicCollection.Topic>(s => s
.Query(q => q
    .FunctionScore(fs => fs
        .Name("function_score_query")
        .Query(q1 => q1
            .MultiMatch(c => c
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Field(p => p.field1)
                    .Field(p => p.field2) //...etc
                .Query(searchTerm)
            )
        )
        .Functions(fun => fun
            .ScriptScore(ss => ss.Script(sc => sc
                .Inline(
                //TODO: add 1000 to normalised _score if match is in field1
            )))       
        ).BoostMode(FunctionBoostMode.Replace)
    )
).Highlight(h => h
    .Fields(p => p.AllField())
    )
);
```

Comment: Based on the TODO comment, I think an easier way to achieve this would be to apply a boost to `p.field1` in the `multi_match` fields

Comment: @RussCam Doesn't a boost multiply? I am looking to normalise the _score to between 0 and 1, and then add to it so that the _score will always be less important than which field the match was on.

Comment: Boost is not a simple multiplication - `_score` is normalised after boost is applied, so increase is not linear. Why do you want to normalise the score between 0 and 1? I think a suitable boost would work, or if you'd prefer a multiplier, a weight function with filter in a function score query

Comment: I need all results that were from field1 to always appear above all other matches. Within that I want to order by year (I thought I could add the year as a number). Then within that I want to order by the _score, so I normalised it to always be a smaller number. I guess I have misunderstood the boost - can this all be done using boost?